# vidia, laptop, try install nvidia driver, xorg no device found

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, debian

when i install nvidia driver and reboot computer i get black screen, if i delete xorg configuration all ok, but i not use nvidia to dispaly.

```
matx132@matx132:~$ lspci | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)

matx132@matx132:~$ lspci | grep -i nvidia
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104M [GeForce GTX 880M] (rev a1)

root@matx132:/home/matx132# uname -a
Linux matx132 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u4 (2015-09-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

link to xorg logs
[xorg logs pasteit](http://ctrlv.it/id/2489/2333368906)
can help anybody me?, how to use nvidia driver?

my laptop is asus G750JZ

Comment: your driver is not loaded or incompatible. `[     3.814] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)`

Comment: any suggest how to repair this ?

Comment: Try to follow guides in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the driver is available. Follow [this guide.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvid)

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall everything NVIDIA related you have installed before.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Then install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers and Optimus support.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime 
sudo reboot
```

Open **NVIDIA X Server Settings** -> **Prime Profiles** - switch to **NVIDIA** - log out and back in.

Answer (score 0):

The below answer is only applicable if your laptop has nvidia Optimus:

delete everything that has nvidia*

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
```

install nvidia-common else no driver will install:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-common
```

I got my optimus laptop "almost" working with bumblebee/nvidia. The only problem is throttling due to overheating.

Basically you do this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

sudo apt-get update
```

install bumblebee and the nvidia driver

sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia nvidia-352 nvidia-352-uvm nvidia-settings primus
then you need to sudo gedit /etc/modules and add

```
i915

bbswitch
```

then you need to sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/bumblebee.conf and make sure the line

```
blacklist nvidia-352
```

is there, if not add it.

finally you need to sudo gedit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf

line 22:

> Driver=nvidia

line 55:

> KernelDriver=nvidia-352

line 58:

> LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-352:/usr/lib32/nvidia-352

line 61:

> XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-352/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules

reboot.

This answer comes from: http://rajat-osgyan.blogspot.gr/2015/05/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-driver-in.html

see there for more explanation. It is approved by many (and me)to work, though the difference is that i don't use ppa:xorg-edgers (since it is unstable) and use graphics drivers ppa and ppa:bumblebee/stable, i recommend you do that instead.

Games run "almost" fine and i can use my both my cards simultaneously.
Use

```
PRIMUS_SYNC=1 primusrun %command%
```

in steam game->properties->set launch options to run a game

Samsung NP550-P5C S02GR
intel core i5-3210m, GT 650M